# Rework find command to work with additional extension

Tags: linux, shell, makefile

I have a trouble with find command in Linux. In my makefile I have a variable in which I save all .c code files (I found this in the internet)

```
source_files = $(shell find ../src -type f -iname '*.c' | sed 's/^\.\.\/src\///')
```

But I want to add the additional extension - *.cu and *.cpp, not only *.c

For example:

```
source_files = $(shell find ../src -type f -iname **'*.c;*.cu;*.cpp'** | sed 's/^\.\.\/src\///')
```

Of course my code is not working.

How I can change the code to work with additional extensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain search criteria together in `find` with `-o`:

`source_files = $(shell find ../src -type f -iname '*.c' -o -iname '*.cu' -o -iname '*.cpp' | sed 's/^\.\.\/src\///')`

You can also use regex search:

`source_files = $(shell find ../src -type f -regex ".*\.\(c\|cu\|cpp\)$" | sed 's/^\.\.\/src\///')`